# Really simple JavaScript "Inheritance" (Example with questions)

Tags: javascript

[I also have this running example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajb6m/1/)
Sample:

```
function Animal(o) {
    o.class = Animal;
    o.name = o.name ? o.name : "Animal"; // Defaults
    o.age = o.age ? o.age : 0; // Defaults
    o.weight = o.weight ? o.weight : 0; // Defaults
    o.say = o.say ? o.say : "?";

    Animal.isOnEarth = true; // "static variable"

    return o;
}
function Cow(o) {
    o.class = Cow;        
    o.name = o.name ? o.name : "Cow"; // Defaults
    o.milk  = o.milk ? o.milk : 0; // Defaults
    o.say = o.say ? o.say : "MOOO";

    return Animal(o); //Inheritence
}
function Dog(o) {
    o.class = Dog;        
    o.isCrazyLab = o.isCrazyLab ? o.isCrazyLab : false;
    o.say = o.say ? o.say : "WOOF";

    return Animal(o) //Inheritence;
}

function Labradore(o) {
    o.class = Labradore;        
    o.isCrazyLab = o.isCrazyLab ? o.isCrazyLab : true;
    o.say = o.say ? o.say : "YARRWL";

    return Dog(o) //Inheritence;
}

var cow = Cow({});
var bessy = Cow({name:"bessy",milk:25});
var spot = Dog({name:"spot"});
var hugo = Labradore({name:"hugo"});

document.write("True or false, all these animals live on earth " + Animal.isOnEarth + " A cow says " + cow.say + "... bessy's name is " + bessy.name + " a " + spot.name + " says " + spot.say + " " + hugo.name + " says " + hugo.say);
```

I've got a small project that I'm working on and I wanted to implement a type of inheritance. I looked at some of the samples online but I don't quite understand why it would be important to go through all the rigamaroll of modifying basic behaviors in javascript. To me it feels like extending the class concepts of javascript to make it "feel" like another language may save a few lines but doesn't appear to add much core functionality. However, I am more than happy to be schooled :)

Some questions
Is there any libraries that work in this manner?
Any online examples of the pros and cons of doing this?
Is there a fundamental reason NOT to do this?
Any general thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not really inheritance, it's basically copying. Not that terminology necessarily matters here. :-)

The main downsides I see are:

- `instanceof` won't work
- You lose out on the mechanisms JavaScript provides for sharing resources across implementations (the prototype chain).
- It's surprising, at odds with other objects defined in the language. I don't expect to always have to pass an object into constructors, and I expect to use `new` with them.
- No clear way to call a "super"'s version of a function.

---

**Off-topic**: A couple of notes:

- `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript. You shouldn't use it as an identifier, just as you wouldn't use `for` or `if` as an identifier.
- You can simplify a bit by using the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html), e.g.:

  ```
  o.name = o.name || "Cow"; // Defaults
  ```

Comment: @samwise: No worries. If you're interested, I've done a fairly thorough article on inheritance in my blog: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html I've been meaning to revisit it to change the terminology away from "class" concepts, because it's just JavaScript's standard prototypical inheritance peppered with some syntactic sugar, and I've come to believe that using "class" terminology with JavaScript should only be done informally, since it doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 2):

My own issue is as follows:

```
document.write(hugo.class == Animal) // true
document.write(hugo.class == Labradore) // false
```

Comment: Hah! Good call! I suppose I could add the same check into class

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using John Resig's "[Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)" script. (John Resig is the guy in charge of jQuery: genius. I'd strongly suggest reading through his post if you haven't already.

This syntax looks so much cleaner and less error-prone to me:

```
var Animal = Class.extend({
    name : "Animal",
    age : 0,
    weight : 0,
    say : "?"
});
Animal.isOnEarth = true; // "static variable"

var Cow = Animal.extend({
    name: "Cow",
    milk: 0,
    say: "MOOO"
});
```

Comment: I was looking at that, this part was the only thing I took issue with: (Copy the properties over onto the new prototype... begin loop)... I don't know why, and maybe that isn't a big deal, but the concept of iterating over and manually checking each property felt like overkill

Comment: @samwise: Think of John's script as a "framework." It takes care of the nitty-gritty details of inheritance, which means you don't have to do it "manually."

Comment: Resig's script isn't too bad, but sadly it relies on function decompilation for its supercall support. It's a bit hidden away, but it decompiles functions subclasses override via `Function#toString` (implicitly, by passing them into `RegExp#exec`). The problem there being that `Function#toString` has never been standardized and in fact doesn't work on some mobile browsers. It also happily assumes that if "_super" appears anywhere in the method -- inside a string, as a variable name, whatever -- that you want the supercall magic wrapped around it, which obviously isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I'm reading through the comments on Resig's post, and it looks like it checks to see whether the browser supports function decompilation, and if it does then it uses regex to determine whether a call is made to the `super` method. This just allows it to avoid wrapping the function if it never calls `super`. It uses decompilation (if it's available) to perform this optimization, but it doesn't *depend* on it, per se.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it does. That means that on engines where it's not supported, every method call will end up being a call to a wrapper which then calls your actual method. Could be worse, and the supercall syntax is wonderfully simple.